# cannot find the .so library when use link_directories() and target_link_libraries() in cmake

Tags: c++, shared-libraries

Ubuntu shows: **/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibswmm5**, ,when i use the CMakeLists.txt below. To figure out what CMake has done,i use make VERBOSE=1, it showd the address problem, even after i tried **export LD_LIBRARY_PATH='pwd'**

```
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable Tutorial
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/Tutorial.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/c++     CMakeFiles/Tutorial.dir/tutorial.cxx.o  -o Tutorial  -llibswmm5 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibswmm5
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

i tried the two versions below (according to modern CMake, find_librarires() is encouraged to use), i thought they should work, but none of them work:(. I am a starter for CMake. If anyone could give some comments on this small problem, it would be much appreciate.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(Tutorial)
add_executable(Tutorial tutorial.cxx)
link_directories(${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR})          
target_link_libraries(Tutorial libswmm5)
```

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(Tutorial)
add_executable(Tutorial tutorial.cxx)
find_library(SWMM5_LIBRARY
       NAMES 
          libswmm5
       HINTS
          ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/prebuilt/
)

if ( NOT SWMM5_LIBRARY )
      message( WARNING "SWMM library NOT FOUND")
else()
      message( STATUS "SWMM library : ${SWMM5_LIBRARY}")
endif(SWMM5_LIBRARY)
  target_link_libraries(Tutorial ${SWMM5_LIBRARY} )
```

Comment: `target_link_libraries(Tutorial libswmm5)` should be `target_link_libraries(Tutorial swmm5)`

Comment: offtopic: use of `link_directories` is discouraged in modern cmake.

Comment: Hello @273K, I just check the shared library, it indeed named as libswmm5.so. Then i tried the target_link_libraries(Tutorial swmm5), same error showd again. ***/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lswmm5***

Comment: `-lswmm5` is a proper use.

Comment: Does this library supports `cmake` and/or `dpkg`?

Comment: Hello @MarekR, I am not quite sure about this, but this library was compiled with CMakeLists.txt as well. I thought is should work with cmake

Comment: @273K, thank you, i would change it to swmm5.so

Comment: No! Do not rename the file, keep the proper name `libswmm5.so`. You seem miss basic knowledge about app linking.

Comment: When building this library did you run: `cmake --install .`? How did you build or install this library?

Comment: @273K, thank you, Just googled its difference, if i use gcc compiler, i need to name it the way that link describes, it is proper as you said. Thanks anyway:)

Comment: @MarekR, First i run cmake .. then cmake --build .             i did not install it.

Comment: I just changed the libswmm5 to swmm5 in find_library() in the second version CMakeLists.txt. It works!!! So the point is the basic knowledge of linking and avoiding to use link_directories(). Thank you both :) @MarekR and 273K